# Is there a way to use file_get_html on a series of webpages in one script?

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I have a database full of links in a MySQL table and I would like to parse each of them and move the output to a new file. Unfortunately, I get an error that "Cannot redeclare file_get_html()" whenever I use include("getContent.php") inside of a while loop.

My main script is

```
<?php
$db = 'newsfeed';
$zeta = 0;
$beta = 0;
// connect to RDS instance MySQL Database Newsfeed
include_once('/var/www/dbfunctions/mysqli_connectdb.php');

// set content source table 
$sourcetable = 'feedsources';
$mastertable = 'mastertable';

// set date to remove results older than
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$datenow = date_timestamp_get(date_create());
$offset = "86400";
$deldate = $datenow - $offset;

//begin cycling through content data

//delete all "old" entries from the mastertable

//get number of source items present
$itemquery = "SELECT id,name FROM $sourcetable";
$itemresult = mysqli_query($conn, $itemquery);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemresult)) {
$sourceid = $row['id'];
$sourcename = $row['name'];

        // cycle throught the data tables 
        $dataquery = "SELECT * FROM $sourcetable WHERE id = $sourceid;";

        $dataresult = mysqli_query($conn, $dataquery);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataresult)) {
        $table = $row['datatable'];
        }

        // copy all data from the targetted table into the master table 


       //loop through the targetted table and copy to mysql
        $getdata = "SELECT * FROM ".$table.";";
        $datareturn = mysqli_query($conn, $getdata);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datareturn)) {
                $date = $row['datecreated'];
                $title = addslashes($row['title']);
                $url = addslashes($row['url']);
                $tags = addslashes($row['tags']);
                $titleid = $row['id'];

        //get content and place in html file in /var/www/html/nuzr/content/

                include("getcontent.php");
                echo $filename;
                //check whether the item already exists in the table
                $checkquery = "select id from ".$mastertable." where title = '".$title."';";

                $checkcheck = mysqli_query($conn, $checkquery);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($checkcheck) > 0){
                echo "CHECKFAILED";
                }else{

                $copy = "INSERT INTO ".$mastertable." VALUES ('NULL','$table','$sourcename','$date','$title','$url','$tags','$filename');";
                mysqli_query($conn, $copy);

                echo "Beta is ".$beta;
                $beta = $beta + 1;
                        }
                }
        // clean the master table
        $delquery = 'DELETE FROM '.$mastertable.' WHERE datecreated < '.$deldate.';';

        mysqli_query($conn, $delquery);

}

function clear()
{
    $this->dom = null;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->children = null;
}

?>
```

and the getcontent.php script is

```
<?php
//Check Start
//echo "Program Starts";

// Include the library
include('/var/www/tools/dom/simple_html_dom.php');

$source = $url;
$content = array();
$header1 = array();
$header2 = array();
$i = 0; $y = 0;

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html($source);

        //grab headers in case initial title is a header
        foreach($html->find('h1') as $e){

                $header1[$i] = $e->outertext;

                //echo $e->outertext;

                $i = $i + 1;
        }

        $i = 0;

        foreach($html->find('h2') as $e){

                $header2[$i] = $e->outertext;

                //echo $e->outertext;

                $i = $i + 1;
        }

        //reset counter
        $i = 0;

        // Find all paragraph tags and print their content into a text file
        foreach($html->find('p') as $e){

                $content[$i] = $e->outertext;

                //echo $e->outertext;

                $i = $i + 1;
        }

//create the content storage file
$filename = "/var/www/html/nuzr/content/".$table.$titleid.".html";
echo "The filename is".$filename;
$file = fopen($filename,"a");

// write header and link to original article
$titleblurb = "<b>Original article courtesy of <a href='".$url."'>".$sourcename."</a></b>";
fwrite($file, $titleblurb);

// set site specific parameters based on header / footer size
if($sourcename == "The Globe and Mail"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 13; $y = 2;

        //Add Header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        $text = $header2[1];
        fwrite($file, $text);

}elseif($sourcename == "CNN Money"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 3; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        $text = $header2[1];
        fwrite($file, $text);

}elseif($sourcename == "CNN Markets"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 3; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        //$text = $header2[1];
        //fwrite($file, $text);

}elseif($sourcename == "BBC Business"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 9; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        //$text = $header2[1];
        //fwrite($file, $text);

}elseif($sourcename == "BBC Politics"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 0; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        //$text = $header2[1];
        //fwrite($file, $text);

}else{
echo $sourcename;
}

        do{

        $text = $content[$y];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        $y = $y +1;

        }while($y<$z);

echo "Zeta is".$zeta;
$zeta = $zeta +1;

//close the content file
fclose($file);

//echo "File end.";

$html->clear();
unset($html);





?>
```

Apologies for the somewhat messy program. I've added a lot of counters and stuff into it in the process of troubleshooting the issues.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated. Currently the program experiences a fatal error and doesn't run. I've seen a few situations where people had similar issues and it was suggested that they use include_once() instead of include(), but this doesn't work since it means you only get one of the target URLs parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make this function in a separate file, or paste it into the

```
if (!method_exists('file_get_html')) {
    function file_get_html() {}
}
```

Comment: Sorry but... wouldn't that just stop it from running the second time and thus only result in one of my URLs processing?

Comment: try replace include('/var/www/tools/dom/simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('/var/www/tools/dom/simple_html_dom.php');

Comment: Ah wow. I literally just realized this is the stupidest mistake ever. I am looping the getcontent program but it includes the library declaration. I just moved the line include('/var/www/tools/dom/simple_html_dom.php'); into my primary routine and it all works. Thanks for your help. I was way too focused on my primary routine.